# find the child entities with specific property in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-relationship

following is my code and relationship between the entities,

```
public class Expense
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int ExpenseId { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public int CategoryId{ get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
  public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

  public virtual List<EditedExpense> EditedExpenses { get; set; }
}
public class EditedExpense
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int EditedExpenseId { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public int CategoryId{ get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
   public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

   public int ExpenseId { get; set; }
}
```

As you see EditedExpense is a child of Expense. Now I want to find all Expenses that their CategoryId OR the CategoryId of their EditedExpense is equal to a particular integer. Something like this:

```
db.Expenses.Where(exp => exp.CategoryId == 1)
    .Include(exp => exp.EditedExpenses.Where(editeExp => editedExp.CategoryId == 1));
```

But it casts an exception and saying

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
>   Parameter name: path

Am I missing something?

Comment: why don't you just do the filter againts `EditedExpense` ? if `Expense` CategoryId is invalid, then all `EditedExpense` underneath it must be invalid too right?

Comment: all Expenses has valid CategoryId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem here is the code

```
db.Expenses.Where(exp => exp.CategoryId == 1 || exp.EditedExpenses.Any(ee => ee.CategoryId == 1).Include(exp => exp.EditedExpenses);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can do without the .Where in our .Include call and simply place your condition within the .Select call:

```
 db.Expenses
      .Where(exp => exp.CategoryId == 1)
      .Include(exp => exp.EditedExpenses
           .Select(editedExp => editeExp => editedExp.CategoryId == 1));
```